# Where does the power $2$ come from in the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

So

$$a^2+ b ^2 =c^2$$

in a right triangle, but where does the power $2$ come from?
I know we can use different metrics in the Euclidean space. If we use the $p$-metrics, where $p$ is in place of $2$, the case $p=2$ is the only one that makes $\mathbb{R}^n$ an inner product space (right?). So it's the only case where we can even talk about right triangles.

But I guess my question is then that is there some sort of underlying (physical) reason for the exponent $2$?

Comment: In the classical sense, the pythagorean theorem is about an equivalence of areas (of squares with sides equal to $a,b,c$), does that answer your question?

Comment: Isn't it like asking where does 2 come from in the area of a square $a^2$? It's pretty much by definition. Pythagorean theorem is just saying sum of 2 areas is equal to the 3rd.

Comment: Yes, but if you use for example the $1$-metric it becomes $|a|+|b| = |c|$. My question is more like why is the square-metric 'the right one'.

Comment: What about higher dimensional analogs? [De Gua's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua's_theorem) talks about _squares_ of _areas_? Can we still say we 'square' because we have actual squares?

Comment: Einstein began with $E=m\cdot a^2$ and crossed it out, then tried $E=m\cdot b^2$ and crossed it out. Then he wrote $E=m\cdot c^2$ and said: Heureka!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was answered in the comments, the $2$ in the Pythagorean theorem simply stems from the fact that it talks about the areas of squares.

Regarding your other question, you are right. The Euclidean norm is the only $p$-norm that makes $\mathbb{R}^n$ into an inner product space and thus the only norm w.r.t. which it makes sense to speak of right angles (i.e. orthogonality).

You can see this by the following:

> **Fact:** A normed real vector space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ can be equipped with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ such that $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$ if and only if the *parallelogram identity* holds:
>   $$2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)=\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2$$
>   for all $x,y\in V$.

Answer (score 1):

For another perspective, look at Bhaskara's proof (http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~demo5337/Group3/Bhaskara.html).  You inscribe a square in a larger square by properly selecting a point on each edge of the larger square and connecting them in rotational order.  Then you show that the area of the smaller square, whose side is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, is correct for the Pythagorean theorem.

This construction relies on the fact that a square is self-dual. That seems so obvious we tend overlook it -- but self-duality fails for measure polytopes in higher dimensions.  There are too few faces in a cube or hypercube to match up with the vertices, and a Bhaskara-type construction is doomed to fail.  From this point of view the exponent 2 ultimately comes from a unique property of two-dimensional space.